# Search for lines starting with given string in Vim?

Tags: search, regular-expression

I have this code snippet:

```
# import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
def foo():
    ...
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    ...
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

How should I specify search query, that it would find only the uncommented `ipdb` lines?

I guess the command could look something like: `/import ipdb/(line start flag)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this:

```
/^[^#]*ipdb
```

The first `^` will anchor the match to the start of the line, `[^#]` will match
any character *except* a `#` (the `^` means to match any character *except*
those given), and the `*` repeats this 0 or more times.

See:[`:help /^`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5E)
[`:help /[`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/collection) for some more information.

Note that this will match all lines with `ipdb` which don't start with a comment, including:

```
import other_module, ipdb
```

---

If you only want to match those starting with `import ipdb`, you can use:

```
/^\s*import ipdb
```

Here `^` will again anchor the match to the start of the line, `\s` will match any whitespace character, and `*` repeats this 0 or more times.

Comment: @niekas, then add `\s*` between `/^` and `[^`.

Comment: So the final query is: ``/^\s*import ipdb``. Thats exactly what I wanted.